# query sql join and where clause

Tags: php, sql

First table employee

```
id   empName     empEmail           empSal   active
====================================================
13   sadf        asdf@sdf.com       233       1
12   checkout    cherckout@g.com    3         1
11   safg        asdf@asdf.com      123       1
10   sdf         sadf@sdf           4         1
9    sdaf        asdf@sdf.com       3         1
8    asdf        asdf@sdf.com       8         1
7    asdf        asdf@sdf.com       8         1
6    asdf        asdf@sdf.com       8         1
```

Second Table emp_status

```
id  emp_id  EmpSalary  active
=============================
5   4       156        1
4   2       156        1
3   2       555        1
2   1       200        0
1   1       1500       1



SELECT o.*
FROM employees as o
LEFT JOIN emp_status as emp ON emp.emp_id = o.id
WHERE (emp.active IS NULL OR (emp.active != 0))
GROUP BY o.id
ORDER BY o.id DESC
```

If emp_status has two rows one having status 1 and other having status 0 what we want it should not count to 1 if I have zero it should help out the execution. how could it be possible?

Comment: can you elaborate more i don't get it? you want to skip those employees which have 0 status?

Comment: please post expected outcome.

Comment: add `SELECT count(o.id) AS cnt` if you want count

Answer (score 2):

Don't pass join table condition on where clause and I suggest you active column datatype =ENUM And set value 0,1,2,3,4,5,6

```
SELECT o.* FROM employees as o
LEFT JOIN emp_status as emp ON emp.emp_id = o.id and emp.active IN (1,2,3,5,6) GROUP BY o.id ORDER BY o.id DESC
```

Comment: Look at second Table emp_status emp_id has active value 0 it should not display but still displaying

Comment: you want get emp.active=NULL ?

Comment: what you want get emp.active=NULL ?  or  emp.active=1 ?

Comment: I do not wish to load that is null or is not zero and !=4

Comment: so you want to get emp.active=1 means active record i am right ?

Comment: active status can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 we just want get that does not belongs to 0 or 4

Comment: Just look emp_status table for emp_id 1 it is having 2 values one is set 0 and other is set 1.

Comment: if any employee not have enrty with emp_status table then you want to get this employee or not  If your answer is not then remove join type = left